# Selenium tests now failing in gitlab.com's gitlab-CI runners?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gitlab, selenium-chromedriver, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I had some selenium-based tests running happily on gitlab.com's gitlabCI runners for months, but they started failing one week ago with this:

```
Unhandled Exception:
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:37385/session timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request timed out
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) <0x401dafd0 + 0x0018b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () <0x401b57f0 + 0x00053> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request) <0x4020d770 + 0x000bc> in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request) <0x4020d770 + 0x00463> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute (OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.Command commandToExecute) <0x401eb570 + 0x00197> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute (OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.Command commandToExecute) <0x401cc480 + 0x00074> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute (System.String driverCommandToExecute, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 parameters) <0x401cc160 + 0x000a6> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession (ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) <0x401cbef0 + 0x000cd> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor (ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) <0x401cb8e0 + 0x000c7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor (OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService service, OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout) <0x401c4b10 + 0x00067> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor (System.String chromeDriverDirectory, OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout) <0x401b7dc0 + 0x00037> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor (System.String chromeDriverDirectory, OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions options) <0x401b7d60 + 0x00037> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at canopy.core.start (canopy.BrowserStartMode b) <0x401b6000 + 0x00b43> in <filename unknown>:0 
...
```

We haven't changed **anything** at the time they started failing, so there's not any code change to rollback. Then I'm wondering if something changed on gitlab's side? Like if they decided to make their runners have no internet connection at all or something like that? But I don't see anything related to runners in the release notes of the recently-released versions.

Anybody has a clue of what might be wrong here?

PS: We're using an ubuntu 16.04 docker image to run the tests, although I guess it's not really relevant here.